# uploading a file to S3, using boto3. i don't know what to replace the <FMI> with

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

```
import boto3
S3API = boto3.client("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
S3API.**<FMI>**(Bucket="tiwaladebucket")

import boto3
S3API = boto3.client("s3", region_name="us-east-1") 
bucket_name = "tiwaladebucketcatfound"

filename = "../cat.jpg"
S3API.**<FMI>**(filename, tiwaladebucketcatfound, "cat.jpg", ExtraArgs={'**<FMI>**': "image/jpg", "CacheControl": "max-age=0"})

filename = "../index.html"
S3API.**<FMI>**(filename, tiwaladebucketcatfound, "**<FMI>**", ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "text/html", "CacheControl": "max-age=0"})
```

Comment: Sadly its not clear what you want to do, what is the issue, what errors do you get.

Comment: Hey Marcin. On lines (3,8, and 10), i don't know what to replace the "FMI"(Fill me in) with.

Answer (score 0):

You are s3 client and need to use put_object API to upload files to S3

```
S3API.put_object(Body=binary_data, Bucket='my_bucket_name', Key='s3folder/path/filename.txt')

or 

S3API.put_object(Body=file_object, Bucket='my_bucket_name', Key='s3folder/path/filename.txt')
```

Reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object

Alternatively, you can use S3 resource instead of S3 Client and perform the same

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')    
s3_resource.Bucket('bucketname').upload_file('/local/file/a.txt','folder/path/to/s3key')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple **FMI** and as I can see, they are not to be replaced by the same command. More information about what the code is trying would be nice, but my guess is that you want to:

- create the bucket "iwaladebucket"
- upload two files to said bucket "../index.html" and "../cat.jpg"

Using your code from above, the following would achieve this:

```
import boto3
s3client = boto3.client("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
s3client.create_bucket(Bucket="tiwaladebucket")

bucket_name = "tiwaladebucket"

filename = "../cat.jpg"
s3client.put_object(filename, bucket_name, "cat.jpg", ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "image/jpg", "CacheControl": "max-age=0"})

filename = "../index.html"
s3client.put_object(filename, bucket_name, "index.html", ExtraArgs={'ContentType': "text/html", "CacheControl": "max-age=0"})
```